# How to identify IDP entity in OpenLogin SCIM Provisioning

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, onelogin, scim, scim2

In any B2B Web application users has to be provisioned against an entity.  For example, Acme company users shall be provisioned for Acme entity only.

I am trying to test my user provisioning APIs with OneLogin "SCIM Provisioner with SAML" connector.  But I am not sure how to identify the user's organization entity.

Is there any way to identify user's organization entity other than bearer token?

Answer (score 1):

The most 'user-friendly' (integration admin friendly?) way is to use the bearer token. This way the SCIM URLs that a client talks to will always be the same. Additionally, you're enforcing which entity is being affected.

The other (less common) way I've seen an application implement this is by using a unique URL per entity. i.e. `https://` **`entity_name`** `.ServiceProvider.com/SCIMUrl/`

But even if you go with this unique URL mechanism, you're going to have to make sure the bearer token was created for that specific tenant (otherwise I can use my token to access another tenant's data)

So you might as well implement it the first way, in my opinion.